# Backbone.js accessing elements which fired a View's event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I need to access some information about the element that was bound to a Backbone View's events (i.e. the `href="something"`). How do I access this object?

```
var SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        "click a.some-class": "doStuff"
    }

    doStuff: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent default behavior
        // How can I access the element (i.e. a <a>) here?
    }

});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`$(e.target)` will work.

```
doStuff: function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   $(e.target).css('color', 'red');

 }
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/aD3Mn/2/

Comment: `this` refers to the Backbone view in that case, not the element

Comment: @dlrust:  Thanks, I forgot that Backbone binds it automatically.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: It should be `e.currentTarget`, because `e.target` can be a child of `a.some-class`. Drove me nuts.